# Testing the database connection in Yii framework

Tags: yii

The following commands produce errors. And have only been working with yii 4 days now.. please help to solve this.

```
C:\wamp\www\yii\trackstar\protected\tests\unit>phpunit DbTest.php
'phpunit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to install phpunit. See http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/383/setting-up-phpunit-and-selenium-with-intellij-idea-phpstorm/ for some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error states that PHPUnit is not installed in you WAMP stack.

The easiest method to install it is using PEAR. Try following this method to install PHPUnit with PEAR :

Go to the directory where PHP is located. Typically, this is \bin\php\php5.3.8

We’ll call this path “PHP’s location”

1. Download “go-pear.phar” from this location:
   pear.php.net/go-pear.phar

   Create a folder “pear” in your PHP’s location

   Put the downloaded “go-pear.phar” file in this location.
2. Open a command prompt with administrative privilege. For this, click
   on start menu, type “cmd” – you can see the cmd.exe icon.
   Right-click on this icon and click “Run as administrator”

   Cmd.exe will open. Go to the direcotry of your PHP’s location, by
   typing “cd” command. For example, my wamp is located in “D:\wamp”,
   so I write following command:

   ```
   D:
   cd wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8
   ```

   Now run the downloaded file, by typing:

   ```
   php .\pear\go-pear.phar
   ```

   Installation will begin! During installation, you’ll need to respond
   to some prompts, just hit enter/press “Y” when necessary.

   After installing, double-click and instal “PEAR_ENV.reg” found in
   your PHP’s location.

   Optionally, you can add your PHP’s location in your PATH variable.

After you can install PHPUnit like this :

1. Open a command-prompt, go to PHP’s location using cd, and type:

   ```
   pear channel-discover components.ez.no
   pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
   pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
   pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
   ```

   Type **phpunit –version** to confirm installation.

That should install PHPUnit, and now you may try

```
phpunit DbTest.php
```

Hopefully, it should work.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you so much.at this moment i have paused working with Yii and will be back asap. i'll do it as you have stated when i restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set up unit tests then I found it quicker and easier to set up a ubuntu virtual machine. It will only take a couple of hours including PHPunit and selenium server. Whereas you could spend hours or days trying to get PHP paths and system variables right on windows.